# Using non-standard font in web pages?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been told to create a website using a non standard font. The client has supplied the font file (in the .otf format). Is there any way I can have the text on the webpage show up in the specified font (non-web standard) ?

Is there any other alternative other than using sIFR ?

EDIT : How do i apply this @font-face only to a particular div ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is @font-face usable now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219916/is-font-face-usable-now) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-website), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838295/custom-font-and-a-cms), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180029/font-face-in-css-is-it-ok), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512468/using-a-custom-ttf-font-in-css), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985097/custom-font-via-css) and many others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the CSS [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%40font-face) declaration for this.

However, beware: not all browsers support the `otf` format.
You can use a tool such as [FontSquirrel's Font-face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to convert the font into all the different formats you'll need. It'll even generate the CSS for you, which you'll then simply copy and paste into your project.

Comment: Your answer was mostly better than mine so I merged them and deleted mine :). +1

Comment: How do i apply this font-face only to a particular div ?

Comment: The @font-face declaration does not apply the font to your page at all. You need the @font-face declaration so that the font is available for you to use in your page. You can then apply the font to your div via the regular CSS `font-family` property. If you're using FontSquirrel's Generator, you should have a sample page included with the download...

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% supported, but:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url('MyFont.otf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS 3 has given browsers the ability to download and use TTF file formats. As usual IE gives partial support. As usual, Google to the rescue.

http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use Cufon font replacement:

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

It does have some drawbacks however: text can't be copied and it uses javascript which may be a problem in some very old browsers of if someone is browsing with js turned off.

Comment: This was an option in 2011 but today all browsers support @font-face. You still need to convert an OTF font to WOFF though.